# Is there a way to find fully qualified method names in WinDbg?

Tags: windbg, sos

When I want to set a break point using !bpmd, I need the fully qualified method name.

According to the MDSN document ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx), I can find type names using ILDASM.
(So I can find fully qualified method names using ILDASM.)
However, this means I need another separate tool just for searching method names.

The background of this question is:
 I know I can use ‘x’ command for native apps.
As ‘x’ shows symbols, I can find function names easily.
So if there is something like ‘x’ command for .NET apps, I don’t need to use a separate tool.
I usually vaguely remember method names, but I don’t remember fully qualified method names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As 'x' is to native code, !sosex.mx is to managed code.

Download sosex for free from stevestechspot.com.  You can pass wildcards ? and * in your search.  If you just want to set a breakpoint, though, you can just use !sosex.mbm (or !mbp, if you want to break on a source file, line number).